# How to modify variables by their name with for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
b1 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70,bg = "gray", command = lambda: click(b1))
b2 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b2))
b3 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b3))
b4 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b4))
b5 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b5))
b6 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b6))
b7 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b7))
b8 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b8))
b9 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b9))

for n in range(10):
    bn.configure(text=="something") #To modify all buttons with loop
```

How can I modify the buttons dynamically be their name with `for` loop?

Comment: Hi David Kobalia, what exactly is `Button`?

Comment: Just to clarify, the b1-b9 are defined before the loop and you want to update them dynamically using the loop?

Comment: You should definitely use another object capable of holding Buttons.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add import tkinter. It's from tkinter button widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `b1`-`b2` are defined in your global scope and you want to access them dynamically by their name, you can use `gloabls()`:

```
b1 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70,bg = "gray", command = lambda: click(b1))
b2 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b2))
b3 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b3))
b4 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b4))
b5 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b5))
b6 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b6))
b7 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b7))
b8 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b8))
b9 = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70, command = lambda: click(b9))

for n in range(1,10):
    bn = globals()["b{}".format(i)]
    bn.configure(text=="something") #To modify all buttons with loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary of buttons, i.e.

```
dict_button = {}

for n in range(10):
     dict_button['b'+ str(n)].configure(text=="something")
```

And maintain your buttons in the dictionary as

```
dict_button['b1'] = Button(win,padx = 70,pady = 70,bg = "gray", command = lambda: click(b1))
```

Comment: Yeah but is there a better way

Comment: dict will work, but it would be easier with a list.